# Trying to put a variable as command

Tags: python, variables, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telepot

My variable `urls` finds URLs from messages. I want my bot to send `yes` if it finds a URL from the received messages. Here is what I tried,

```
def action(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', command)

    if command == urls:
        telegram_bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "yes", parse_mode= 'Markdown')
```

But it is not working. Is it a correct way to put variables as a command and how to fix it?

Comment: "it is not working" - what isn't working? What did you expect to happen and what actually happened? What is `command`? A string? `urls` is a list of strings, so there could be a problem there.

Comment: Did you checked type of urls and command?

Comment: @Nathan I want my bot to reply `yes` if it finds a URL from the received messages. But it isn't working with what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is that you compare `command` (a string) against `urls` (a list of strings). If you want the message to be sent as long as *at least one* URL was found in the command, you can change this to

```py
def action(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', command)

    if urls:
        telegram_bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "yes", parse_mode= 'Markdown')
```

Note - if there are no matches, `urls` will be an empty list. The boolean value of an empty list is false in Python, so `if urls` only passes if `urls` is not an empty list (i.e. there was at least one match). This is equivalent to saying `if len(urls) != 0:`.

If you instead want a message sent only if the entirety of `command` is a URL, you can do

```py
def action(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

    pattern = 'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'

    if re.fullmatch(pattern, command):
        telegram_bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "yes", parse_mode= 'Markdown')
```